# Congruence transformation on an open set can be extended

Tags: differential-geometry

Here is the original question:

> Let $U$ be an open subset of $E^3$, the Euclidean space, $\mathcal{T}$ is a transformation from $U\to U$ preserving the distance(that is $\forall x,y\in U, d(x,y)=d(\mathcal{T}x,\mathcal{T}y)$). Prove that $\mathcal{T}$ is a congruence transformations.(In our textbook, congruence transformation is defined as the transformation that preserves distance in $E^3$)

My interpretation is that the mapping $\mathcal{T}$ acting on an open set preserving distance can be extended to a mapping acting on the whole space $E^3$ which also preserves distance. But how can I extend this transformation? Just cover the space with these open sets? But I cannot find a good way to deal with the overlapping sections. Hope to find some hints, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is right insofar as it is the only one making sense for the problem statement - since $\mathcal T$ is *not* a map $E^3\to E^3$ (unless $U=E^3$), certainly $\mathcal T$ itself is no congruence transfrmation.

To obtain en extension to all of $E^3$, note that a congruence transformation is uniquely determined by its values on four non-coplanar points. 
Sho that $U$ contains four such points. Then show that the unique congruence transformation determined by such a fourtuple of points coincides with $\mathcal T$.

Comment: Thank you! So I can choose the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ that are linear independent, and $a+v_1,a+v_2,a+v_3 \in U$. Then I will prove if $\mathcal{T} a=u_0,\mathcal{T} (a+v_1)=u_1,\mathcal{T}(a+v_2)=u_2,\mathcal{T}(a+v_3)=u_3$, if $\mathcal{T}$ preserves distance, then it is uniquely determined.Then I will prove that this $\mathcal{T}$ is "linear", that is $\mathcal{T}(a+k_1 v_1+k_2 v_2+ k_3 v_3)=u_0+k_1(u_1-u_0)+k_2(u_2-u_0)+k_3(u_3-u_0)$. But  how to prove that this is unique? Thanks!